# How can I resume playing the video in Brightcove Exoplayer when network connection is re-established?

Tags: android, brightcove, exoplayer

I am using the [Brightcove Exoplayer](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/perform/mobile-sdks/hls-player/guides/exoplayer.html) in my app to stream videos. However, I noticed that it does not handle network interruption completely (disconnect followed by reconnect) on its own.

It is unable to resume playback in the following cases:

1. Once the seek position = buffer position and the device reconnects
   to the data network.
2. If the user seeks backwards or forwards while the data network was
   disconnected and then is reconnected.

Is there any Brightcove-endorsed/explained way to handle these use-cases?

My code:

```
public class BrightCoveActivity extends BrightcovePlayer {

    private static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "<The Auth Token>";
    private static final String TAG = BrightCoveActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView brightcoveExoPlayerVideoView;
    private EventEmitter eventEmmiter;
    private Context mContext;
    private MediaController mMediaController;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bright_cove);
        brightcoveExoPlayerVideoView = (BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView) findViewById(R.id.brightcove_video_view);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = this;

        final Catalog catalog = new Catalog(AUTH_TOKEN);

        fullScreen();

        mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
        brightcoveExoPlayerVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);

        eventEmmiter = brightcoveExoPlayerVideoView.getEventEmitter();

        prepareEventEmmiter(); // puts all event listeners in place.

        catalog.findVideoByID(VIDEO_ID, new VideoListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                throw new RuntimeException(error);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideo(Video video) {
                brightcoveExoPlayerVideoView.add(video);
                brightcoveExoPlayerVideoView.start();
            }
        });

    }

    /*
        More code not related to playback
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way available to handle this case is listen to the network changes inside the app and refetch the video from catalog. You will need to handle various things while you do this (ad management if it is there, keeping the current position in event PROGRESS and reusing the same once catalog fetch got completed etc..)

Comment: That's a Pandora's box. If one is trying to extract video analytics, this becomes quite expensive to handle at the client end.